# Stopping the BufferedWriter from overwirting an existing line of text

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I have a question for those, who know how the BufferedWriter and the BufferedReader work.I want to add a line of Text below the first line that already exists, but Java is giving me a NullPointerException.

Here's the code :

```
String myClass = "none";
File ff = new File("src/Resources/Saves/test.txt");
try{
   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(ff);
   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
   FileReader fr = new FileReader(ff);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
   bw.write(br.readLine()); //NullPointerException is here
   bw.newLine();
   bw.write(myClass);
   bw.flush();
   bw.close();
   br.close();
} catch(IOException ecc){
   ecc.printStackTrace();
}
```

In theory, it should re-write the first line of text, start a new Line and write my String "myClass".

Answer (score 3):

you can use the second constructor of the `FileWriter`

```
new FileWriter("File name",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy a file on top of itself (which wouldn't work anyway) just to append to it, and you can use try-with-resource

```
String myClass = "none";
File ff = new File("src/Resources/Saves/test.txt");
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(ff)) {
   pw.println(myClass);
}
```

I wouldn't catch an Exception unless you plan to do something with it.